# Results from firebird DB columns are nameless just numbers

Tags: php, firebird

I'm using the following code to query my Firebird database, but the results do not include the column names, just numbers. It's my first time working with Firebird, I only worked with MySQL. Is there a way to get column names instead of numbers?

```php
$dbh = ibase_connect($cdb, $this->session->userdata('client_username'), $this->session->userdata('client_password'), 'utf-8', '100');
$rid = ibase_query($dbh, $query);
$coln = ibase_num_fields($rid);
$dataArr = array();
while ($row = ibase_fetch_row ($rid)) {
    $dataArr[] = $row;
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
          [0] => 1
        )
 )
```

How can I get the column name that was `[User_Id]` instead of `[0]`? Is it possible?

Comment: It might be time to finally upgrade to PDO. You shouldn't be using old unmaintained APIs

Comment: Have you tried fetching an associative array instead of numerical one? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: @Dharman That library isn't 'unmaintained', it just isn't part of the standard PHP distribution any more. It is currently maintained on https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/php-firebird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [Dharman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839439/dharman) in the comments, you need to use [`ibase_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-fetch-assoc.php) instead of [`ibase_fetch_row`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-fetch-row.php) to get a result using column names (associative array).

As documented for `ibase_fetch_assoc`:

> fetches one row of data from the result. If two or more columns of the
> result have the same field names, the last column will take
> precedence. To access the other column(s) of the same name, you either
> need to access the result with numeric indices by using
> ibase_fetch_row() or use alias names in your query.

Compared to `ibase_fetch_row`:

> Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row, or false if
> there are no more rows. Each result column is stored in an array
> offset, starting at offset 0.

Answer (score -1):

When you *prepare* a query Firebird returns the resultset information for it, including column datatypes and aliases. Use `fbird_field_info(...)` to query the alias.

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-prepare.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-field-info.php